# What does refeer evil-mode ^ (carry)'s mark to ? (shown in :marks list)

Tags: evil, mark

I Think I have an idea, unless i want to be sure. According to [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks), `[` and `]` marks in vim refers to beginning/end of previously changed or yanked text, but there is no built-in `^` mark.

I must have missed something because I didn't really get deep into evil or vim references manuals.

Any accurate idea ?

Thank you in advance, hoping this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a special mark that stores the last position where you used the Insert mode. From the Vim help:

> '^  `^                  To the position where the cursor was the last 
>   time when Insert mode was stopped.  This is used by the gi command. 
>   Not set when the :keepjumps command modifier was used.  {not in Vi}

You can learn more about the topic in Vim with `:help marks` or in the [Vim online documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#mark-motions)

Comment: thanks .. it's what i thought i should have dug the documentation